# Can we merge tags [dwm] and [dwm-api] please?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are two tags that are used to refer to question about Windows Vista/7/8's Desktop Window Manager, [dwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwm) and [dwm-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwm-api).  They're clear duplicates. Could they be merged, please?

`Dwm` has a suggested synonym of `dwm-api` with no upvotes. `Dwm-api` has no suggested synonyms at all, and I can't suggest one since I don't have enough rep in the tag (a common problem with duplicates I run into quite often.)

A scan of questions marked with both show they are both used for questions about the Windows DWM.

Comment: There is also [this dwm on Linux](http://suckless.org/).

Comment: Perhaps we need a retag then. Of the fifteen questions on the front page of [tag:dwm], 13 are the Windows DWM (exceptions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908848), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886588).) For [tag:dwm-api]... there must be a glitch because I'm suddenly not seeing any. There were quite a lot, a scan made them all seem Windows-DWM-related.

Comment: Note many questions seem to have both tags, too - ie people are aware of the duplication. Presumably they just haven't gone to meta and requested a fix.

Comment: [tag:dwm-api] is now showing results again. @Deduplicator, every single one on the front page of the tag is Windows DWM. If there's another DWM it should probably have its own tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had created a [dwmapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwmapi) synonym for [dwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwm) way back in 2010, but somehow, someone added a hyphen and created a new tag. I missed this Meta question when it was raised in 2014, but it has apparently been done. I'm not sure when, but someone must have gone through and manually retagged all the questions with [dwm-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwm-api), because there weren't any more.

Either way, to stave off its possible reappearance, I made [dwm-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwm-api) a synonym of [dwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwm) (just like [dwmapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwmapi)).

I also created a new [x-dwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x-dwm) tag for [the Dynamic Window Manager for X](http://suckless.org/) that Deduplicator mentioned. I only saw one question using [dwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwm) in that way, so I just retagged that one. I also created tag wikis, and added a bit of usage guidance. Hopefully, these aren't popular enough tags that it'll be a major usage problem.

Comment: I had forgotten all about this question. Three years later... thanks! :)